# Powershell Update sql string throws error at certain char

Tags: powershell

I do a update sql table with powershell.

The field 'Tag' gets the tag value '0.5.2' something is wrong with that value?!

because the error message says:  Incorrect syntax near '.2'.At

Anyone knows whats wrong?

```
0.5.2

[16:05:30][Step 5/5] g6a885b5

[16:05:30][Step 5/5] Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near '.2'.At 

[16:05:30][Step 5/5] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell643608974404729980.ps1:12 char:1

[16:05:30][Step 5/5] + invoke-sqlcmd -query "UPDATE VersionMetaData SET Tag = ${tag}, CommitId = 

[16:05:30][Step 5/5] ${comm ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Tag` field on `VersionmetaData` is likely a string, but SQL Server is attempting a type conversion of 0.5.2 to a decimal number when it parses it (because the data isn't formatted as a string, when it gets to SQL Server). And 0.5.2 isn't a decimal number.

Wrap the tag in single quotes to tell SQL Server it's a string.

Partial query (since we don't have the full code of your script):

```
invoke-sqlcmd -query "UPDATE VersionMetaData SET Tag = '${tag}'
```

It would be safer to not use `invoke-sqlcmd` and string concatenation in this way, as it leaves you open to breakage/corruption/attack via SQL injection, but that would mean doing a heavy rewrite of this portion of your script. A `PreparedStatement` would be a much safer alternative.